# Чат с комнатами на вебсокетах

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, websocket, django-channels

Есть небольшой веб-чат на django с комнатами:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Слева - список чатов, справа - выбранный чат.

Нужен совет, как правильно подключить сокет соединения таким образом, чтобы отлавливать новые сообщения из выбранного чата, и также обновлять список чатов, если сообщение пришло в чате, который не выбран. Есть ли вообще вариант обойтись одним соединением? Или придётся делать несколько, одно для списка чатов, другое для выбранного

Comment: Вам ничто не мешает через единственный канал передавать вместе с сообщением признак того, к какой комнате оно относится.

Comment: [Это видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4haMUvUxUJI) должно развеять туман